# SocketAsyncEventArgs buffer is full of zeroes

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, asyncsocket, io-completion-ports

I'm writing a message layer for my distributed system. I'm using IOCP, ie the Socket.XXXAsync methods.

Here's something pretty close to what I'm doing (in fact, my receive function is based on his):
http://vadmyst.blogspot.com/2008/05/sample-code-for-tcp-server-using.html

**What I've found now is that at the start of the program (two test servers talking to each other) I each time get a number of SAEA objects where the .Buffer is entirely filled with zeroes, yet the .BytesTransferred is the size of the buffer (1024 in my case).**

What does this mean? Is there a special condition I need to check for? My system interprets this as an incomplete message and moves on, but I'm wondering if I'm actually missing some data. I was under the impression that if nothing was being received, you'd not get a callback. In any case, I can see in WireShark that there aren't any zero-length packets coming in.

I've found the following when I Googled it, but I'm not sure my problem is the same:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ncl/thread/40fe397c-b1da-428e-a355-ee5a6b0b4d2c

http://go4answers.webhost4life.com/Example/socketasynceventargs-buffer-not-ready-121918.aspx

Comment: I haven't had any data processing errors from lost data, so I think there's nothing lost. But that still leaves the question of why the method would return with nothing, several times.

Comment: It is hard to provide solution for you need without your brief description (with code). However I had experience with Sockets and I can recommend to use higher abstraction - Network Stream. Network Stream has all capabilities of Async callback that you want to use. Look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.networkstream.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.networkstream.beginwrite.aspx HTH

Comment: Is it the same underlying calls? It sounds useful. Also, the code I'm referring to is in the link.

Comment: I don't have an answer for you, but maybe this will provide some insight: a while back I was doing a project in .NET 3.5 for a university course with my friend. We encountered a strange behavior, where on one version version of Windows, the Buffer was empty, and on the other it was full of zeroes. The version were WinXP and Win7, but I don't recall which way around.

Comment: @Carlos Yes Network Service is only abstraction to standard Socket communication, and extended to more new useful features. I recommend that you create PoC (Proof of Concept) project and try it. It is worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

I am sure not what is going on in the linked example. It appears to be using asynchronous sockets in a synchronous way. I cannot see any callbacks or similar in the code. You may need to rethink whether you need synchronous or asynchronous sockets :).

To the problem at hand stems from the possibility that your functions are trying to read/write to the buffer before the network transmit/receive has been completed. Try using the callback functionality included in the async Socket. E.g.

```
// This goes into your accept function, to begin receiving the data
    socketName.BeginReceive(yourbuffer, 0, yourbuffer.Length,
        SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(OnRecieveData), socketName);

// In your callback function you know that the socket has finished receiving data
// This callback will fire when the receive is complete.
private void OnRecieveData(IAsyncResult input) {
    Socket inSocket = (Socket)input.AsyncState; // This is just a typecast
    inSocket.EndReceive(input);

    // Pull the data out of the socket as you already have before.
    // state.Data.Write ......
}
```

Comment: The callbacks are the event handlers on the SAEA objects. I've actually run the code with some minimal grammatical errors.

Comment: Is it possible for you to paste your receiver code into pastebin or similar, I have only seen the example you are basing yours upon.